# Is there a way to know the new launched sites over the years?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, graduating-sites

Stack Exchange now has more than 170 sites. Is there a way to know when those sites were launched?

I know I can download all dumps and figure it out, but is there any cheaper way to do so?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest or https://normalhuman.github.io/timeline/

Comment: What do you mean by "launched"? By A51 terminology, "Launched" actually means the same as "graduated"... it's the date that a site leaves beta.

Comment: How do you define "launched"? Would the time of a private beta count? A public beta? The "graduation" time (an [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) term)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to do this.

**Method #1**: If you know the name of the site, then go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), search for the site, and the proposal will say in the top right corner when it graduated. Example:

[image]

This way does not work for sites that never had an Area 51 proposal, such as Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow.

**Method #2**: Go to [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) on stackexchange.com (it's easiest sorted by name so you can find the site you're looking for), and on the far right side it will show the age of the site in years and months.

[image]

Comment: Why is there no mouse-over text giving the date (for either options you present)? Related question on Area51 Discussion: [Tooltip showing date/time of site launch](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20646/90733)

Comment: @Werner that, I do not know. It seems natural that both of them should have a tooltip. That's actually a really good feature request: add a tooptip to show the exact date of graduation or time since graduation.

Comment: Yes. Most (all?) timestamps have a date/timestamp tooltip on mouse-over/hover. I'll ask a follow-up on my Area51 feature request here on Meta, to see whether it has more traction.