# Add time stamp tooltip to site launches/age

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, timestamps

This is a follow-up question/request to [Is there a way to know the new launched sites over the years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324795/168244) and is related to this Area 51 discussion: [Tooltip showing date/time of site launch](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20646/90733).

The [All sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) via of Stack Exchange gives tooltips for most of the raw variables shown, except for the site age.

[image]

Please add the site (launch) dates as a tooltip, similar to what is common for all dates on the site.

[image]

It will provide consistency associated with date references across the entire network.